# SQL insert query with values like JUM'A ABDUL FATTAH causing missing , error

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to insert data into a table which is derived dynamically.
I am selecting data from MASTER_TABLE which has col1 and col2. Depending on the values in col1 and col2, I am inserting the data in table SLAVE_col1value_col2value.

my sql query looks like:

```
insert_query_str :='INSERT INTO SLAVE_'
        || Col1
        || '_'
        || Col2
        || ' VALUES ( '''
        || CUST_NAME
        || ''','''
        || APPLICATION_DATA
        || ''')';
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE insert_query_str;
```

However, name like JUM'A ABDUL FATTAH cause the insert query string to look like this

```
INSERT INTO SLAVE_XYZ_ABC VALUES ( 'JUM'A ABDUL FATTAH','APPSPECIFICDATA');
```

and I get a missing comma error on the line. 
I know if I double quote the name then this error can be sorted out but when I try that it hardcodes the || too and I don't get the real name in the query.

I am using Oracle SQL 11g and Toad.

Thank you in advance

Comment: use bind parameters, not string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use placeholders together with `USING` clause:

```
insert_query_str :='INSERT INTO SLAVE_'
        || Col1
        || '_'
        || Col2
        || ' VALUES ( :cust_name, :app_data )';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE insert_query_str USING CUST_NAME, APPLICATION_DATA;
```